# Package libgeotiff-epsg is not available and has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt, system-installation, package-management, software-installation

I am installing openstreet server on Ubuntu and for that I need to install libgeotiff-epsg package. When I do `sudo apt-get install libgeotiff-epsg`, it it returning that

> Package libgeotiff-epsg is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libgeotiff-epsg' has no installation candidate

I have gone through many sources on google but not able to resolve this issue. Could anyone tell me how should I install this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` add

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse
```

Save

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgeotiff-epsg
```